# Firebase App Distribution new build alerts on Android

Tags: android, firebase-app-distribution

In-app build alerts exist on iOS. It's a beta release feature. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/set-up-alerts).

Does this exist on Android yet? Is it possible? I can't find any information.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist yet.
They have been saying "it's in the roadmap" since 2019... draw your own conclusions.